# What is the name of the dance the conductor breaks into during a fight in Martin Scorcese's “The Aviator.”

Tags: analysis, the-aviator

In Martin Scorsese's *The Aviator*, in  the night club, when a tablemate takes a piece of food of Hughes plate and he reacts by leaving a few minutes later. Errol Flynn is drunk throughout this scene and after Hughes leaves the night club Flynn is involved in a fight.

But the band plays on and the music conductor “dances” something where his body arches and he throws out his arms while falling from one foot to the other, like some kind of march. I've seen it before in old movies.

What is this dance called and is there any background info or story behind it. There's a video can be seen below; The fight starts at 3:01 into the clip:

Comment: I believe that this was originated by Cab Calloway in the early 30's and copied by several big bandleaders.  I don't think that this particular "dance" has a name, though.

Comment: We'll call it "steelerfan shuffle," then, and hope that Landry Jones does that right out the door.

Comment: @AndrewMattson Amen, brother! :)

Comment: "INT, COCOANUT GROVE NIGHTCLUB NIGHT: An explosion of 1930's glamour. A sea of tuxedos and shimmering dresses. The orchestra bounces something with a rolling swing edge. Dancers float around the dance floor in imperfect imitations of Fred and Ginger." is what the script says - https://assets.scriptslug.com/live/pdf/scripts/the-aviator-2004.pdf